# Menu for purchasing tequila and whiskey

Tags: beginner, c

I would like to hear some feedback about style on my program, and which one is better "do while" or "while loop" to run my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define Tequila 20
#define Whiskey 25




int main()
{


    int choice = 0;
    int bottle1= 0;
    int bottle2= 0;
    int final_total= 0;
    int total1 =0;
    int total2 =0;

    do{
        printf("\tMain Menu MK liquor Store\n");
        printf(" \tEnter your choice: \n");
        printf("\t 1-  Buy Tequila Jose Cuervo\n");
        printf("\t 2-  Buy Whiskey Jack Daniels\n");
        printf("\t 3-  Quit\n");

        scanf("%d", &choice);



        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("how many bottles of Tequila would you like\n");
                scanf("%d", &bottle1);
                printf("so far you got %d bottles in your basket \n", bottle1);

                break;
            case 2:
                printf("how many bottles of Whiskey would you like\n");
                scanf("%d", &bottle2);
                printf("so far you got %d bottles in your basket\n", bottle2);


                break;
            case 3:
                total1=bottle1 * Tequila;
                total2= bottle2 * Whiskey;
                final_total = total1+total2;
                printf("You obtained %d bottles of Tequila and %d of Whisky\n", bottle1,bottle2);
                printf("Your total  is %d dollars\n",final_total);

                break;
            default:

                printf("ERROR INVALID OPTION.\n\n");

                break;

        }

    }while (choice != 3);
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: As far as "do-while" vs "while" loop, I would suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3625759) SO question.

Comment: @Jamal given that the title is now "Menu for purchasing tequila and whiskey", I wondered whether I was on [Cooking.SE]. And I really hope that the title does not apply to too many questions :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to hear some feedback about style on my program,

The vertical spacing is excessive.

Odd separation example: blank lines between `case` code `printf("so far you got %d bottles in your basket\n", bottle2);` and `break;` misleads code blocks.  Consider instead;

```
        case 2:
            printf("how many bottles of Whiskey would you like\n");
            scanf("%d", &bottle2);
            printf("so far you got %d bottles in your basket\n", bottle2);
            break;

        case 3:
```

`{` at line end or next line:  Stay consistent

```
do{
...
    switch(choice)
    {                  // why here vs above line
```

I'd expect following to be less indented.

```
       return 0;
```

It is apparent code is **not written using an *auto formatter*** and **that is the biggest style problem**.  Any style worth using will match an auto formatter.  Manually formatting is not productive and too inconsistent.

---

> and which one is better "do while" or "while loop" to run my program.

Use of `do()` is OK here as the loop should always execute at least once.  Some style guides eschew `do()`.  As will such styles issues, follow your group's coding rules.

---

Style aside, code not checking the result of an input function like `scanf("%d", &choice);` is weak.

```
// better
if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1)  {
  break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chux
Do you know , how can I activate the auto formatter in Codeblocks

Comment: @Mike I am not familiar with Codeblocks.  You may need a 3rd party tool.  Tip: It is worth the time to learn how to let automatic tools take care of the irksome task of formatting code.

Comment: One more thing. The program has an issue when the user type something that is not an interger, it keeps rolling the program without stop. Any recommendations Thanks

Comment: The _robust_ solution is to read all user input with `fgets()` and then parse it with `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc.  A cheap solution is to `getchar()` a character when `scanf("%d"...` fails.